# Aggregate functions on tag values in influxdb

Tags: influxdb

I am writing a query in InfluxDB where my measurement have multiple tags. I would like to group by on a particular tag and time and do a mean on a field and also get the last value in that group for another tag value.

For example:
I have 2 tags: `tag1` and `tag2` and a field `field1`.
I would like to `GROUP BY` on `tag1` and do a `mean` on `field1` and take the `last value` of `tag2`.

For this when I write a query like this, I do not get the tag value:
`SELECT mean(field1), last(tag2) FROM "measurement" GROUP BY tag1`

Please let me know if I am doing something wrong. My `tag2` value is a `string` field.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I was finally able to make it work for me:

`SELECT tagValue,newField FROM (SELECT mean(currentField) AS newField FROM forever.theData WHERE currentField > 0 AND time > now() - 100d GROUP BY time(1d),tagValue)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible with a single query. You [cannot call](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/functions/#last) `last` on a tag key: tags are bound to fields, therefore you must select a specific fields last value. Then you can also query a tag bound to that field value. Also, if you write `mean(field1)` and `last(field1)` in one `SELECT` statement you cannot retrieve `tag2` for `last(field1)` (it cannot be determined if it's for `mean` or `last`). You should try something like this:

```sql
SELECT mean(field1) FROM "measurement" GROUP BY tag1
SELECT last(field1), tag2 FROM "measurement" GROUP BY tag1
```

Comment: strangely this query worked : select mean(field1), last(tag2) from (select mean(field1) from measurement group by tag1, tag2) group by tag1

Comment: BTW, last can be called on the tags as well... it is documented https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/functions/#last